# chai-http treats two different fields with the same name as if as one field

Tags: testing, chai, chai-http

I use mocha and chai-http to test [my api server](https://glitch.com/~fcc-stock-price-checker-isemaj) . The problem is that it treats the query `{stock: 'msft', stock: 'aapl'}` as if it is `{ stock: 'aapl' }`.

**Test :**

```
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var chai = require('chai');
var assert = chai.assert;
var server = require('../server');

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Functional Tests', function() {

    describe('GET /api/stock-prices => stockData object', function() {

      it('1 stock', function(done) {
       chai.request(server)
        .get('/api/stock-prices')
        .query({stock: 'goog'})
        .end(function(err, res){
          console.log(res.body);
          //complete this one too

          done();
        });
      });

      it('1 stock with like', function(done) {

      });

      it('1 stock with like again (ensure likes arent double counted)', function(done) {

      });

      it('2 stocks', function(done) {
        chai.request(server)
          .get('/api/stock-prices')
          .query({stock: 'msft', stock: 'aapl'})   // <-- THIS ONE
          .end(function(err, res){
            console.log(res.body);
            done();
          });
      });

      it('2 stocks with like', function(done) {

      });

    });

});
```

**Result :**

```
1. Uncaught error outside test suite
Functional Tests
 GET /api/stock-prices => stockData object
{ stockData: { stock: 'GOOG', price: '1019.8300', likes: 14 } }
   / 1 stock (532ms)
   2) 1 stock with like
   3) 1 stock with like again (ensure likes arent double counted)
{ stockData: { stock: 'AAPL', price: '185.7900', likes: 7 } }
   / 2 stocks (360ms)
   4) 2 stocks with like
```

The output `{ stockData: { stock: 'AAPL', price: '185.7900', likes: 7 } }` shows only one stock. It is expected to return

```
{"stockData":[{"stock":"MSFT","price":"104.5600","rel_likes":-5},{"stock":"AAPL","price":"185.7900","rel_likes":5}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the fault of `chai-http`, it's the fault of JavaScript: you can't have an object with two identical keys.

But I think that you can also pass an actual query string to `.query()`:

```
.query('stock=msft&stock=aapl')
```

Comment: Thank you. But `.query('stock=msft&stock=aapl')` doesn't work. I instead remove the `.query()` and replace the `get()` with `.get('/api/stock-prices?stock=msft&stock=aapl')`.